# Panel Control doesn't update

Tags: c#, controls

I have Panel Object on my page , I want to replace it with another Panel

```
//Info.panel[cb_page_number.SelectedIndex] = pnl_page_active;
Panel new_panel = new Panel();
new_panel.BackColor = Color.White;
//new_panel.Name ="page_"+ (cb_page_number.SelectedIndex+1).ToString();
//cb_page_number.Items.Add(new_panel.Name);
//cb_page_number.SelectedIndex = cb_page_number.Items.Count-1;
pnl_page_active = new_panel;
pnl_page_active.Refresh();
pnl_page_active.Update();
Application.DoEvents();
```

pnl_page_active has a ivory background color,And there is some controls on that. When I execute above code I expext to see pnl_page_active background has been changed and there is no control on that,But it's the same,So I'm wondering what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have done is assigning new_panel variable to pnl_page_active. It has nothing to do with Control hierarchy.

You need to remove the old panel from it's parent and insert the new one:

```
Control parent = pnl_page_active.Parent;
if (parent != null) {
    parent.Controls.Remove(pnl_page_active);
    parent.Controls.Add(new_panel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're currently doing is modifying `pnl_page_active` to reference the same Panel that `new_panel` is... but `new_panel` was never added to the Form, so you don't see the color change.

Remove all the code you posted above, and just change the `BackColor` directly:

```
pnl_page_active.BackColor = Color.White;
```

If you want to replace the existing Panel with the new one (for whatever reason), you'll have to make sure it has the same parent, size, location, etc, in addition to whatever attributes you're copying.

```
Panel new_panel = new Panel();
new_panel.BackColor = Color.White;
new_panel.Size = pnl_page_active.Size;
new_panel.Location = pnl_page_active.Location;
new_panel.Parent = pnl_page_active.Parent;
new_panel.Show();

pnl_page_active.Hide();  // or Dispose if you don't want it anymore
```

Comment: Thanks! But as you can see in the first line of my code I save the pnl_page_active in some static class,because I want get it back to my main form whenever I want to,and properties are more than just size,location etc,It has some events that has been changed programmatically,